# Semantic analysis in C#

Tags: c#, nlp, semantics

What are the tools, if any, to make a C# code that does semantic analysis? I am interested in detecting sysnonims, for example, if there is a sentences with a word K9 in it, the tool would recognize that K9 means dog.

Comment: [This Google search](https://www.google.com/#q=Semantic+analysis+in+C%23) brought up some promising results, especially [this one.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/hh543918.aspx)

Comment: @RobertHarvey I think the OP is more after semantic analysis of English that can be consumed via C#.

Comment: What are sysnonims? If you mean synonyms, Why you require a tool for that? Simply construct a hash table from thesaurus. Parse your text and search for each word in hash table.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What your looking for is a [Natural Language Processing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_language_processing) (NLP) tool, there are a few tools around that could be some help such as [SharpNLP](http://sharpnlp.codeplex.com/) but I'm not aware if there is a specific tool for detecting and replacing synonyms.

Comment: OP asked for semantic analysis tools in C#, this is the closest thing I could think of that may help them. If they do go down this route and build a synonym detection lib then perhaps the sharhnlp would be of use.

Answer (score 1):

A better route these days would be to use ikvm along with something like opennlp.  SharpNLP, mentioned already, is from 2006, is grossly outdated and is dead.  There was one effort to revive it, but that stalled.  You likely will not see any more pure .net solutions because one can use ikvm to access the already existing, mature NLP projects.